# How do I destructure this given code into an HTML table and display it?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

My instructor has given us this code and asked me to destructure the given code creating and displaying an HTML table. I can destructure it using loops displaying it in the console, but thats as far as I've gotten. How can I display the data into a table using destructuring??

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='output'></div>
    
    <table id="table" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>Spoken Languages</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
      var userList = {
        "people": [
          { firstName: "Fred",
            lastName: "Smith",
            dateOfBirth: 1980,
            spokenLanguages: {
              native: "English",
              fluent: "Spanish",
              intermediate: "Chinese" }
          },
          
          { firstName: "Monica",
            lastName: "Taylor",
            dateOfBirth: 1975,
            spokenLanguages: {
              native: "Spanish",
              fluent: "English",
              intermediate: "French" }
          },

          { firstName: "Maurice",
            lastName: "Edelson",
            dateOfBirth: 1992,
            spokenLanguages: {
              native: "English",
              fluent: "Spanish", }
          },

          { firstName: "Kelly",
            lastName: "Lang",
            dateOfBirth: 1982,
              spokenLanguages: {
              native: "English",
              fluent: "German",
              intermediate: "Dutch" }
          }
        ]
      };
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `console.table(userList.people);` ;)  but in all seriousness, use a template engine or view framework...

Comment: Loop through the array, creating elements as you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that destructuring each person object adds a lot of benefit here, however, I will assume it's meant to be a learning exercise.

You will need to use a loop to iterate over the `users.people` array. This could be a `forEach`, `for`, `for in`, or I have chosen a `for of` loop.

You can then destructure the `person` object on each iteration, and use the separate variables to create and append new DOM elements to the `table#table` DOM element.

```js
const table = document.getElementById('table');
const users = {
  people: [
    { 
      firstName: "Fred",
      lastName: "Smith",
      dateOfBirth: 1980,
      spokenLanguages: {
        native: "English",
        fluent: "Spanish",
        intermediate: "Chinese" 
      }
    },

    { 
      firstName: "Monica",
      lastName: "Taylor",
      dateOfBirth: 1975,
      spokenLanguages: {
        native: "Spanish",
        fluent: "English",
        intermediate: "French" 
      }
    },

    { 
      firstName: "Maurice",
      lastName: "Edelson",
      dateOfBirth: 1992,
      spokenLanguages: {
        native: "English",
        fluent: "Spanish", 
      }
    },

    { 
      firstName: "Kelly",
      lastName: "Lang",
      dateOfBirth: 1982,
      spokenLanguages: {
        native: "English",
        fluent: "German",
        intermediate: "Dutch" 
      }
    }
  ]
};

for (const { firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, spokenLanguages } of users.people) {
    const row = document.createElement('tr')
    table.appendChild(row);
    
    const nameTd = document.createElement('td');
    nameTd.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${firstName} ${lastName}`));
    row.appendChild(nameTd);
    
    const dobTd = document.createElement('td');
    dobTd.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dateOfBirth));
    row.appendChild(dobTd);
    
    const spokenLanguagesTd = document.createElement('td');
    spokenLanguagesTd.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Object.values(spokenLanguages).join(', ')));
    row.appendChild(spokenLanguagesTd);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='output'></div>
    
    <table id="table" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>Spoken Languages</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below are links to the documentation for the functions used in the example:

- [Document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- [Document.createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)
- [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
- [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)